# Dual-boot on separate drives

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot

I have a computer with two drives - SSD and HDD, with Windows 7 installed on SSD.

I've installed Linux (Debian netinst) on HDD. I didn't want to mangle with Win installation *in any way* so I selected to install GRUB on HDD - expecting to be able to boot it when I select to boot from HDD.

But when I do, a black screen with this text appears:

```
selected boot device failed
```

Legacy boot is selected (no UEFI), secure boot is turned off too. Windows is working fine, same as before.

What em I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

---

EDIT: I thought I might have forgotten to set the boot flag, so I've tried to do it again and now this text appears:

```
missing operating system
```

Comment: How do you boot from a DVD/USB, with a boot menu of some type? Does it not work when booting the HD? Are you sure you installed grub to the HD?

Comment: Did you disconnect the SSD when you were installing Linux? Was your Windows on SSD also Installed in Legacy Mode? What happens when you select SSD for booting, does it boot Windows correctly?

Comment: No, I did not disconnect SSD. I don't know how was Windows installed. Windows is booting correctly.

Comment: You do not have to disconnect the SSD when installing Linux, but you do have to select your install options carefully... I do this all the time, both OSs must be installed the same BIOS mode (legacy or EFI) but they must be the same. Install Windows normally, then when installing Linux make sure to install the bootloader (GRUB) to the boot sector of the seconds (Linux) hard drive. In BIOS/EFI make sure the second hard drive is listed as a boot option, and on boot start the Boot Menu, select HDD0 to boot Windows, and HDD1 to boot Linux (or whatever drives are appropriate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install grub into the hdd: `grub-install /dev/sdX`, or if you install it in a partition, you should make that partition bootable (e.g. with `cfdisk`. (Because the HDD is not the first hard disk, possibly Debian didn't complain about not setting bootable flag on such disk.

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: Do a grub install again to <code>/dev/sdX</code>, so you should not use <code>cfdisk</code>.  Or you may want to reconfigure GRUB:<code>dpkg-reconfigure -plow grub-pc</code>.

Comment: Okay, I've repaired GRUB from *rescue mode* and it seems to be working.